# Django: CREATE data in Database via multiprocessing can cause `too many clients already`?

Tags: django, postgresql, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm running my `django` application, which getting data from websocket API and store them in my `PostgreSQL`

Here is the part of code:

```
class MyWebsocketClient:
    .
    .
    def process_message(self, msg):
        # Get msg from websocket server forever (until I force to quit the program)
        self.data_buffer.append(msg)
        if len(self.data_buffer) > 3000:             
            pool = Pool(cpu_count() * 2 // 3)
            pool.map_async(store_data, self.data_buffer)
            self.data_buffer = []


def store_data(data_buffer):
    BinanceTick.objects.create(
        field1=self.data_buffer['t'],
        field2=self.data_buffer['p'],
        field3=self.data_buffer['q'],
    )
```

This works pretty well, in a parallel way.

But when I tried to make query to the same database in other interfaces (such as `jupyter` or `django-shell-plus`), it occured errors:

```
OperationalError: FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

Why does it happen? Below are what I can think about:

1. Each `Pool` still have a connection with DB even after it finished its task
2. I should have added `pool.close()`
3. what else

What's the main problem?